# Is Flex 4 Panel's controlBarContent dynamic?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, panel, flex-spark

I have a custom TitleWindow component (written in ActionScript) that extends spark.componenets.TitleWindow

I want to define some controls to be in the control bar but I don't have all controls at the creation stage. Also, this custom component is the base for other components which need other controls in the control bar.

Is there a way to add controls to the controlBarContent in ActionScript at run time?

Maybe something like the following? (this obviously didn't work)

```
controlBarContent = [];
.
.
.
controlBarContent.push(new Button());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, look out for

```
addElement()
```

or

```
addChild()
```

methods.

addElement() adds other UI components as sub-elements of other components.

[This](http://patrapatisunil.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/use-addchild-for-halo-containers-and-addelement-for-spark-containers/) might be of interest. Finnaly, Adobe provides good help here: ['Working with components'](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff9.html).

**UPDATE-1**

Sorry, my fault. This works for me:

```
<s:Panel creationComplete="init();" id='p' controlBarVisible="true" >

    <s:controlBarContent>

        <!-- will show controls -->
        <s:Button label="dd">

        </s:Button>

    </s:controlBarContent>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Button;

            import spark.components.Button;

            private function init(): void {

                var s:spark.components.Label = new spark.components.Label();
                s.text = 'My Label';
                s.width = 200;

                var a:Array = new Array();
                a.push( s );

                p.controlBarVisible = false;
                p.controlBarContent = a;
                p.controlBarVisible = true;

                p.invalidateDisplayList();

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to work. For some reason I tried only pushing new items to the array which didn't yield the required result.

Comment: Confirmed! This seems to be the only option to make things work.